# Странные ошибки в visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

Уважаемое комьюнити, столкнулся с проблемой в visual studio, которое невероятно раздражает. А именно: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом ошибки в 6-ой строке нет.
Содержимое students.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "student.h"
class students {
private:
    vector <student> list;
public:
    void adding();
    void show();
    void looking_for();
    //void sorting();
    //void writing();
    //void delete_some();
    students();
    ~students();
};
```

Буду очень признателен за любые мысли на счет этой проблемы.

Содержимое student.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "students.h"
#include "other_func.h"
using namespace std;
class student {
private:
    string name;
    string surname;
    string adress;
    string universety;
    double score;
public:
    void set();
    friend ostream & operator <<(ostream &ost, student obj);
    string return_name();
    string return_surname();
    student();
    student(string oname, string osurname, string oadress, string ouniversity, int oscore);
    ~student();
};
```

То есть, все, что надо объявить, было объявлено.

Comment: student.h - покажите содержимое

Comment: Отсутствует `#include <vector>`, отсутствует пространство имен перед `vector <student>` и, надо полагать, аналогичные проблемы имеются в `student.h`

Comment: Текст программы надо вставлять текстом, а не скриншотом

Comment: Ну где взять ясновидящего, чтоб посмотреть, что там. в `"student.h"`? И вообще - читайте о том, [каким должен быть код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Comment: Код student.h добавлен.

Comment: видимо придется ещё и `students.h` показать. Чувствую,там где то в конце нет точки с запятой или есть лишняя.

Comment: Так он там представлен.

Comment: Ага, не подумал я, что там два файла инклудят друг-дружку. Разрешите эту проблему для начала. Скорее всего стоит удалить эту строку `#include "students.h"`

Comment: Понял, спасибо.
Это было решением проблемы.

Comment: Я бы еще порекомендовал в заголовочные файлы, не пихать ненужные инклуды. Лучше их подключить в файле реализации класса, когда в заголовках они нужны лишь для идентификации типов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, вы включаете первым в программу `student.h`.

Тогда вы получаете в тексте сначала объявление класса `students`, которое начинается как

```
class students {
private:
    vector <student> list;
```

но в этот момент компилятору неизвестно, что такое `student`. Вот он и ругается...

И, кстати, когда он доходит до `vector`, то он не понимает, о чем речь - потому что

```
using namespace std;
```

у вас включено в результате после объявления `students`...

Интересно, что если вы включите первым `students.h`, то из-за того, что он сначала включает `student.h` - то все заработает.

Но вообще-то избегайте таких включений, когда А включает Б, а Б включает А - даже при наличии `#pragma once`... Как минимум - результат зависит от порядка включения, а это нехорошо...

Comment: хотя бы мои комменты почитали...

Comment: @KoVadim Когда их много и они свернуты... Но если вы так к этому относитесь - могу удалить ответ. Но, заметим, что если автор включит в программу сначала `students`, то программа заработает :) - а этого в вашем комментарии нет.

Answer (score 1):

Классическая ошибка зацикленного включения заголовочных файлов друг в друга: `student.h` включает `students.h`, а `students.h` включает `student.h`.

Не пытайтесь включать заголовочные файлы друг в друга зацикленным образом - это ничего не дает, а приводит лишь к "необъяснимым" ошибкам.

Comment: хотя бы мои комменты почитали...